# Is there a way to create subArray chunks of n elements from a given array in Scala?

Tags: arrays, scala, multidimensional-array

Given Scala arrayBuffer: 
`ArrayBuffer(200, 13, 1, 200, 15, 1, 201, 13, 0, 202, 14, 3, 199, 10, 2, 199, 11, 3, 199, 96, 2)`

Expected output: 
`ArrayBuffer((200, 13, 1), (200, 15, 1), (201, 13, 0), (202, 14, 3), (199, 10, 2), (199, 11, 3), (199, 96, 2))`

Is there any simple way of achieving this form of chunking in Scala without for loops? The required chunk_size is 3. And the order of these elements must be the same.

I've tried:

```
def chunkArray(myArray){
    val chunk_size = 3
    var index = 0
    var arrayLength = arrayToInsert.length
    var tempArray =  ArrayBuffer[Int](2)
    val numChunks = arrayToInsert.length / 3
    for (i <- 0 to numChunks-1) {
        var myChunk = arrayToInsert.slice(i*chunk_size, (i+1)*chunk_size)   
        tempArray += (myChunk(0), myChunk(1), myChunk(2))
    }
}
```

Expected result: 
`((200, 13, 1), (200, 15, 1), (201, 13, 0), (202, 14, 3), (199, 10, 2), (199, 11, 3), (199, 96, 2))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `.grouped(3)`

( the collections API [examples](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/examples-scala-sequences-collection-methods-seq-list-array-buffer) )

```
collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer(200, 13, 1, 200, 15, 1, 201, 13, 0, 202, 14, 3, 199, 10, 2, 199, 11, 3, 199, 96, 2).grouped(3).toArray 

res2: Array[collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int]] = Array(ArrayBuffer(200, 13, 1), ArrayBuffer(200, 15, 1), ArrayBuffer(201, 13, 0), ArrayBuffer(202, 14, 3), ArrayBuffer(199, 10, 2), ArrayBuffer(199, 11, 3), ArrayBuffer(199, 96, 2))
```

Comment: Note that  the final element in the `Array` may have fewer that 3 values if the size is not a multiple of 3.

Answer (score 1):

This will create a `Buffer` of tuples, which is what the original code appears to attempt.

```
import collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
val data = 
  ArrayBuffer(200, 13, 1, 200, 15, 1, 201, 13, 0 /*etc.*/)

data.grouped(3).collect{case Seq(a,b,c) => (a,b,c)}.toBuffer
//res0: Buffer[(Int, Int, Int)] = ArrayBuffer((200,13,1), (200,15,1), (201,13,0) /*etc.*/)
```

Note that if the final `group` is not 3 elements then it will be ignored.

Comment: `filter(_.size < 3)` might be a bit clearer than the `collect` (or even `withFilter` to avoid creating a new `ArrayBuffer`)

Answer (score 1):

This could also be achieved using sliding:

```
myArray.sliding(3, 3).toArray
```

Anyway, .grouped is better suited for this use case as discussed here [Scala: sliding(N,N) vs grouped(N)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32874419/scala-slidingn-n-vs-groupedn)